# Can you change the process template for a Team Project in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-process-template

I have a project in VS2013 online. It was setup with the default Process template (Scrum 2.0). I have a lot of source code with history but have nothing else, no workitems/backlog/tasks/stories/bugs etc.
I would like to change the template to the Agile template but cant see a way to do this. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

1) **If you are using VSO then no.**

Your only option would be to create a new Team Project. If it is a TFVC project you will be able to branch your source into the new project on the same instance.

2) **If you are using Team Foundation Server then you can**

Its very strait forward for your circumstance. I would however sugest that the Agile template is not right for you :

- [Change Process Template](http://nakedalm.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/)
- [Template Choice](http://nakedalm.com/agile-vs-scrum-process-templates-team-foundation-server/)

My recommendation is to keep the Scrum template but if you really want User Storys then rename PBI to user story. If your PM's want Original Estimate and Completed Work fields then add them. You are bot going to get far into agility if you are fighting against the tool...

P.s. Feel free to email me to discuss offline

Comment: Is it possible for him to do this with Visual Studio Online? Wouldn't he need to create a new team project that uses the new process template but which branches from the existing code?

Comment: You are correct I failed to see the online as the 2013 distracted me. I have corrected the answer to include both options.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change project template in visual studio team services when you are going between processes derived from same master template. E.g. I took Agile template and added few more states to features.

To change process templates in vsts:

1. Open process lists page (/_admin/_process)
2. Click ... next to process template you want to use to show popup menu
3. Select "Change team project to use "...